# powershell script to send mail

Tags: powershell

i want to write a power shell script in which i want to write  a farm backup command and it should fire a mail on backup error.

please help me to do this.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here you jave the script about the backup

http://weblogs.asp.net/shahar/archive/2008/02/02/powershell-script-to-backup-sharepoint-site-collection.aspx

and here about the email

http://www.myexchangeworld.com/2010/07/send-email-through-powershell/

Comment: gilloux, i want to sent conditional mail.
i mean when error occurs in backup then it should shoot an email.

Comment: You can use the trap and try/catch systen in powershell

I looked up this : http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2009/09/14/trap-and-try-catch.aspx